# How to send a image url to android app on html button click?

Tags: android, html, android-studio

Hi I want when i click on a image(maybe a link around the image) in my website to load that image on my android app:

I have achieve to open my app with a link like this:

```
<a href="allplayer://site.com">Test link</a>
```

and this in my manfest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>

        <data  android:scheme="allplayer" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

but i want the image to change so my app can load different images depending on which one you clicked.

somehow to pass the image url from my web page to my android app

image link could be like this :

```
<a href="www.example.com" rel="image001"><img src="http://www.example.com/image001.jpg"  /></a>
```

When its clicked:
it should open my app and load the image inside.

here is the code i've use to successfully load ANY image from the web:

```
    ImageView bindImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    String pathToFile = "http://www.example.com//image.jpg";
    DownloadImageWithURLTask downloadTask = new DownloadImageWithURLTask(bindImage);
    downloadTask.execute(pathToFile);

    // load image from url #2
private class DownloadImageWithURLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;
        public DownloadImageWithURLTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: href is redirect the url. You can't get from html. you can pass the image url as a parameter of your href <a href="allplayer://site.com?image=http://www.example.com/image001.jpg">img source</html>

Comment: @arun Thanks!
How do i get that to load inside my "String pathToFile = "http://www.example.com//image.jpg";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows

```
ImageView bindImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String pathToFile = intent.getDataString().toString();
    DownloadImageWithURLTask downloadTask = new DownloadImageWithURLTask(bindImage);
    downloadTask.execute(pathToFile);

    // load image from url #2
private class DownloadImageWithURLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;
        public DownloadImageWithURLTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped!

Answer (score 0):

onCreate of receiver activity

```
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            Set names = uri.getQueryParameterNames();               
            if (names.contains("image")) {
                String path= uri.getQueryParameter("image");
                ....                    
            }
        }
```